# Change network route without affecting connection

Tags: networking, routing, connection, ethernet

I would like to know if it is possible to change the network route without affecting the network connection, for example, suppose I have 2GB remaining on one 3g network and 2GB remaining on my Home ethernet connection, and i would like to download a file of size 3.5GB (by switching from one connection to the other) from a file-sharing site that does not support resume i.e if connection ends, I have to start the entire thing from scratch.

Is there some command that i can use to switch over from one interface to the other instantaneously (either Windows or Linux) without disrupting the connection?

Comment: The connection is bound to the local interface; you can't switch, that's a new connection.

Comment: @Joe, is there no command to switch the connection from one local interface to another, or is it permanently bound within the connection?

Comment: @Joe basically, i had researched about the topic. I wanted to know the reason for it not being possible. The main reason i used network-programming tag is that the I initially wanted to develop a program to interface with the adapter to do so. Pls don't downvote the question. I am sure many beginners will have the same doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some command that i can use to switch over from one interface to the other instantaneously (either Windows or Linux) without disrupting the connection?

In theory, if you own provider independent IP address space, you could do what you are asking about as long as you announce that provider-independent IP address block to both of your upstream ISPs.

However, it's rather clear from context that you don't have your own PI block; therefore the answer is no you cannot swap upstream providers in mid-stream.  This is because they are giving you their own ip addressing, and your TCP sockets will rely on that information to remain intact.